# Resize edit rect in image picker iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, cgrect

Is there any way to change the cropRect size for UIImagePickerController when using:

```
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

I want to set my own width and height depending on the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was faced with that issue a while back and at the time there was no way of changing it (I'm pretty sure there still isn't).

I ended up creating my own cropping library. If I'm not mistaken I made use of [SSPhotoCropper](https://github.com/ardalahmet/SSPhotoCropperViewController) as a reference.

Comment: Iv created scrollview to crop and resize after importing the image, but i want the Image to be imported READY for use, am still having problems while zooming i will post question about that if couldn't figure out the problem

Comment: Solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795350/issue-while-zooming-uiscrollview-which-is-used-to-resize-and-crop-image-in-ios